# C++ no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘money << score’

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, fstream

So, I'm trying to make a roulette game where score gets saved to a file called "score.txt" to familiarize myself with file i/o. But I've ran into a slight problem. When I try to compile, I get the error message
*main.cpp:40:15: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘score << money’* (Full message here (248 lines): http://pastebin.com/0TqHxmRx

Previus error message(186 lines): http://pastebin.com/umMdk3fU).
Line 40 in my code is:

```
money_write<< score;
```

I've tried all of the following to see if it will compile:

```
money_write<< score;
score<< money_write;
score>> money_write;
money>> score_write;
```

All of which give a huge error.
Here's the full code (204 lines): http://codepad.org/T5z5vTZH

Here's (probably) the most relevant part of the code (41 lines): http://codepad.org/Rotbu358

Here's the custom header file (wait.h): http://codepad.org/E5qxxAkl

Comment: Could you fix this error message first?
`error: ‘score’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Alright, I fixed it and updated the code URL.

Comment: What are the types of money_write and score?

Comment: Um, your error message changed...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I updated the error message because I updated to code.

Comment: @bstamour score is an int, and money_write is the contents of score.txt

Comment: Well, yes, but that doesn't mean that you don't need to fix the new error first...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Alirght, I have both error messages in the post now.

Comment: I the problem is here `score = money`, where `score` is `int`, but money is `ifstream` on line 32

Comment: @zaufi Alright, thank you!  I was able to fix my code.  It works wonderfully now!

Comment: @eckesicle That wasn't very relevant to my question...

Comment: Perhaps so, but SO is also not your personal debugger. The error in your question did not match the error log you linked to. And the code did not match the error log. Additionally there were a number of other errors, which you could have easily fixed by reading the error message. I guess the goto just pushed me over the edge. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`money` is an in file stream.  About the only valid operator on it is `>>` on the right side of it.  So `money >> score, which you can read as money streaming into the variable score.  Your code is full of other errors as well.

If you get a "no matching" type compiler error, the problem is type based.  Recreate the line in a small file with the same type of variables -- their contents do not matter, just their types.  (Initialize them to avoid warnings).  If the function you are calling is none of your own, all you need is the function signature.  (Linker errors are another matter).

Posting 100+ lines of code is less useful.